# What Does "Full GC Before GC" mean in CMS Garbage Collection Logs?

Tags: java, content-management-system, garbage-collection

I am running an application, using java 5 on Weblogic with the CMS Garbage Collector. In the garbage collection logs, I see logs of messages, most of which I can make sense of using the Memory Managements in Java HotSpot Virtual Machine document from Sun and this helpful blog entry (https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/entry/understanding_cms_gc_logs).

However, there are some entries like this:

```
124525.178: [Full GC Before GC:
Statistics for BinaryTreeDictionary:
------------------------------------
Total Free Space: 353610889
Max   Chunk Size: 353610889
Number of Blocks: 1
Av.  Block  Size: 353610881
Tree      Height: 1
Statistics for IndexedFreeLists:
--------------------------------
Total Free Space: 4190038
Max   Chunk Size: 256
Number of Blocks: 37181
Av.  Block  Size: 119
 free=357800921 frag=0.0233
Before GC:
Statistics for BinaryTreeDictionary:
------------------------------------
Total Free Space: 0
Max   Chunk Size: 0
Number of Blocks: 0
Tree      Height: 0
Statistics for IndexedFreeLists:
--------------------------------
Total Free Space: 0
Max   Chunk Size: 0
Number of Blocks: 0
 free=0 frag=0.0000
```

I've run the file through HPjmeter and there don't seem to be any problems, but the words 'full gc' worry me :-)

What does "Full GC before GC" mean, and is it a stop-the-world event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing two messages on the same line `Full GC` means its is starting a Full GC.  `Before GC` means it is dumping the state of the system before it starts.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. And the Full GC (which I guess is stop-the-world) duration is the figure after the 'After GC' section ?